# Google Maps API v3 marker on click with infowindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I have problem with infowindow. I create marker when i click on map but i want to show infowindow too. This code not working with this part:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});
```

Here is code below.. Thank for help

```
var pridat;
var map;

function initialize() {
    var locc = new google.maps.LatLng(49.938682,17.903331);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 14,
        center: locc,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var contentwindow = '<div>your point</div>'
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentwindow
    });

    // IF I REMOVE THIS PART -> IT WORKS, BUT WITHOUT INFOWINDOW
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });
    // END OF PART

    google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
        placeMarker(event.latLng);
    });
}

function placeMarker(location) {
    if (marker) {
        marker.setPosition(location);
    } else {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: location,
            map: map,
            title: 'My point',
            draggable: true,
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should look at the javascript errors when it doesn't work. You are attempting to use "marker" before it exists.  If you move the 'click' listener for the marker into the placeMarker function where it exists, and make the infowindow globally accessible, it should work.  The code you posted doesn't put any markers on the map.

```
var pridat;
var map;
var marker = null;
var infowindow = null;
function initialize() {
 var locc = new google.maps.LatLng(49.938682,17.903331);

 var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 14,
    center: locc,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                  }

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

var contentwindow = '<div>your point</div>'
infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentwindow
 });

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'rightclick', function(event) {
placeMarker(event.latLng);
});

}

function placeMarker(location) {
if (marker) {
  marker.setPosition(location);
} else {
 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map,
      title: 'My point',
      draggable: true,
     });
   // IF I REMOVE THIS PART -> IT WORKS, BUT WITHOUT INFOWINDOW
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(){
       infowindow.open(map, marker);
   });
 }
}
```

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_markerInfoWindow.html)

Comment: Thank you very much, u help me a lot... but where i can find JS errors in google chrome. I am new in JS, thanks...

Comment: Shift-Ctrl-J (or Tools:Javascript Console)